# How to turn off electric indentation only for TTCN-3 major mode

Tags: indentation

I did some research and I've found few similar questions, but not a single one is able to help me.

Well, recently I've started using [TTCN-3 major mode](https://github.com/dholm/ttcn-el/blob/master/ttcn3.el) and I've found its indentation style awful. I've checked all available c-styles and there is no hope aswell.

I would like to turn off this whole smart indentations that are triggered for example by `indent-for-tab-command` or ending line with semicolon.

As far as I know, due to this:

```
(require 'cc-mode)                      ; ttcn-3-mode inherits from cc-mode
```

major mode `TTCN-3` uses electric-indent-mode. I am trying to turn this off only for `TTCN-3` but my wonderful lisp craft is not working:

```
(add-hook 'ttcn3-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-indent-mode -1)))
```

Could someone please tell me how to do this properly ?

Btw. Should I add hook after or before `load` function in my `.emacs` file ?

Comment: Try electric-indent-local-mode instead.

Comment: Not working either. Maybe I should rebind keys like `TAB` `;` etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it took extra hour, but here it is:

```
(add-hook 'ttcn3-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
            (setq c-basic-offset 4)
            (c-toggle-electric-state -1)
            (setq c-syntactic-indentation nil)))
```

Last two lines are most crucial.